# Implementing a standard layout for reusable components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building reusable UI controls that follow a specific layout and functionality specified in FormLayoutComponent (label, edit/confirm button, read/write view etc).

I currently have to specify the inputs/outputs for FormLayoutComponent in each UI component.

If I ever need to add a new input/output to FormLayoutComponent, I'll have to go through each UI component and update them.

I could have FormLayoutComponent and UI components extend an abstract class. This takes care of the typescript classes but the html template would still require updates if a new property is added.

```
export abstract class AbstractLayout<T = any> {
  @Input() control: FormControl<T | null> = new FormControl<T | null>(null);
  @Output() confirm: EventEmitter<T | null> = new EventEmitter<T | null>();
  @Input() defaultMode: DefaultMode = 'read';
  @Input() showEditButton = true;
  @Input() editButtonIcon = 'edit';
  @Input() showConfirmButton = true;
  @Input() showCancelButton = true;
  @Input() showLabel = true;
  @Input() requireConfirmation = true;
  @Input() label: string = '';
}
```

Is there a better way of doing achieving this in Angular or would I have to update every UI component when a new input/output is added to FormLayoutComponent?

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layout-composition

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in hearing the widsom of the crowd here but in my experience with custom form fields I have found having duplicated HTML being far less messy than having a single component/HTML file with conditional logic for all the possible form field types, especially as these components grow to handle new weird and wonderful requirements.

Unfortunately we don't have a way of extracting reusable "pieces of template" in Angular; the recommendation is to just create components for anything which needs a template, which just doesn't scale in practice for use cases such as a library of 'similar-but-different' form fields.

I am currently using a chain of base classes to abstract out common logic, as you have alluded to. e.g.

```
export abstract class ValueAccessorBase { // ... }
export abstract class FormElementBaseDirective extends ValueAccessorBase { // ... }
export abstract class FormElementValidationDirective extends FormElementBaseDirective { // ... }
export abstract class BaseInputDirective extends FormElementValidationDirective { // ... }
export class FormInputTextComponent extends BaseInputDirective { // ... }
```

*Note: I am abusing the `@Directive` decorator to allow these base classes to accept `@Input()` properties which are then accessible to all the components which extend them. In practice these are all just glorified `abstract class`es (except the final component)*

It's the best solution I have found so far, but suffers from all the typical inheritance problems (which you may never encounter if you have simple component needs). I haven't yet found a way to refactor over to composition due to challenges with `@Input`s/`@Directive`s that inspired [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102590/angular-composition-vs-inheritance-with-inputs)