# Embed contents of angular component directly, without wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Let's say I have a grid like so

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns auto auto;">
    <div>Row 1 Col 1</div><div>Row 1 Col 2</div>
    <div>Row 2 Col 1</div><div>Row 2 Col 2</div>
</div>
```

Which comes out looking like this:

```
|Row 1 Col 1|Row 1 Col 2|
|Row 2 Col 1|Row 2 Col 2|
```

Perfect, just what I want.

Now let's say I want to refactor my code so that each **row** is an angular component

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns auto auto;">
    <app-row-component row=1></app-row-component>
    <app-row-component row=2></app-row-component>
</div>
```

And `app-row-component` looks something like this:

```
<div>Row {{row}} Col 1</div> <div>Row {{row}} Col 2</div>
```

Now the styling of the grid no longer works, because angular wraps the content of `app-row-component` in its own element, and the grid comes out looking like this

```
|Row 1 Col 1 Row 1 Col 2|Row 2 Col 1 Row 2 Col 2|
```

Which is not correct.

Is there a way I can remove the wrapping element of the `app-row-component` so my grid styling still works? Alternatively, is there another way to organize my styling so that I have a grid where each row is a component?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz about your problem?

Comment: Attribute selectors are the best way to solve this issue. see the Nicholas Murray's answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75274212/implementing-a-standard-layout-for-reusable-components-in-angular)

Comment: Try using `display: contents` in your :host styles of the row component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply [`display: contents;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents) to the `app-row-component`.
This will make CSS grid ignore the element and position its children.

Add `styles: [":host { display: contents; }"]` to your component.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqbzf3?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp-row-component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

just move the grid styling one level deeper:

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto;">
      <div>Row {{row}} Col 1</div> <div>Row {{row}} Col 2</div>
    </div>
```

[Sample stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkpcu6?file=src/main.ts)

If you want a higher level styling, then use some classes like this:

```
<div class="row">
      <div>Row {{row}} Col 1</div> <div>Row {{row}} Col 2</div>
    </div>

<div class="table">
      <app-row-2 [row]="1"></app-row-2>
      <app-row-2 [row]="2"></app-row-2>
    </div>
```

And a simple selector:

```
.table .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

Stackblitz is updated.

I tested gre_gor's solution, for me it didn't work. Maybe I do something wrong.

I have updated the stackblitz with `display: contents`, it's working now.

Comment: This does work but it's not ideal as I would like to set the styling at the higher level rather than put it on every single row

Comment: Having each row a separate grid, will fail to size the width of the columns the same, if the content exceeds the width.

Comment: This is true. I have now updated the example with `display: contents`. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommmended but not mandatory to use selectors like `app-row-component`.

You can choose a different selector e.g. `[app-row-component]`:

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns auto auto;">
    <div app-row-component row=1></div>
    <div app-row-component row=2></div>
</div>
```